# Error : Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data <- read_xlsx("path to the file")
data1 <- data[,c(1,20)]  ##getting the two columns
name <- data1[,c(1)]
progdist <- data[,c(2)]
df <- data.frame(name, progdist)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=name, y=progdist)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 0.25)
```

This above code and many others which include me taking the data from excel, shows me the following error.

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
> tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous. Don't know how to
> automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame.
> Defaulting to continuous. Error in is.finite(x) : default method not
> implemented for type 'list'

Tried using `tibble`, but couldn't solve it. Tried the `as.data.frame()` as well. But couldn't understand the `unlist()` function.

Comment: I just checked. The issue is (probably) that there are no columns named `name` and `progdist` in `df`.Check via e.g. str(df). Hence ggplot2 uses `name` and `progdist` which are tibbles. In case of a `data.frame` `data1[,c(1)]` returns a vector, while in case of a tibble the result is a tibble with one column.